# Does "Copy Local" matter if all projects are pointing to the same output folder?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, msbuild

I have a solution of about 50 projects.

I have most of those projects (the non-test ones) setup to output to a single folder.

I have heard that "copy local" can slow down build times (for project references), because it has to copy the file to everywhere it is referenced.

But if every project is copying to the same location is Visual Studio smart enough to see that the file is already there and not copy it again?

So, here is an example:

```
SolutionA
   |
   +---ProjectA (Output set to C:\MyProj)
   |
   +---ProjectB (Output set to C:\MyProj)
   |        References ProjectA
   |
   +---ProjectC (Output set to C:\MyProj)
   |        References ProjectB
   |
   +---ProjectD (Output set to C:\MyProj)
            References ProjectA
```

In a normal solution, copy local would control the copy of the reference to the bin\Debug folder for each of these projects.

But I have updated the "Output" section of the Project Properties so that they all drop to C:\MyProj instead of bin\Debug.

**If I do not set Copy Local to false for references, will ProjectA.dll be copied to C:\MyProj  four times?  Or is Visual Studio smart enough to only do it once?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you are asking is "does it take any time to copy a file onto itself?"  As you might expect, it doesn't.  You can see this by using Reflector or ILSpy on the Microsoft.Build.Tasks assembly, the Copy class performs the copy.  Its DoCopyIfNecessary() method contains this line of code:

```
    if (string.Compare(sourceFileState.Name, destinationFileState.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) != 0)
    {
        flag = this.DoCopyWithRetries(sourceFileState, destinationFileState, copyFile);
    }
```

Or in other words, it skips the copy if the source and destination file are the same.  Necessarily so, File.Copy() won't be happy.

Answer (score 0):

<s>Copy Local copies to the bin directory.  Usually Visual Studio will empty this directory on a Clean command.  If you don't set Copy Local, you run the risk of not having all your references in the bin folder(s).</s>

You can copy them to the bin folder in another way I suppose; but you'd have to do that manually if you ever run Clean...

As far as I know, VS isn't smart enough to see that each project has the same bin directory, so it would copy four times (test and verify though).  In the above scenario you could have only one project with Copy Local and avoid this.  But, you'll need at least one with Copy Local otherwise you'll have situations where your bin directories won't have the file otherwise.

Comment: This was not what I was asking.  I need to know what happens if the projects all point to the same location (so there is only one "Bin Folder").  Please see the example I added to clarify my question.